# Adding 1 to datetime parameter: Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int. Fix in code, not SQL?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

1 - Create a test table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TESTCAL
 (
  TT_CALENDAR_ID INTEGER  NOT NULL,
  TT_START DATETIME NULL,
  TT_FINISH DATETIME NULL,
  TT_EMP_ID INTEGER NULL,
  TT_CAPTION VARCHAR(50) NULL
)
```

2 - Place a `TFDQuery` on the form with SQL command:

```
INSERT INTO TESTCAL
 (TT_CALENDAR_ID
 ,TT_START
 ,TT_FINISH
 ,TT_EMP_ID
)
VALUES
(:ID
 , :TTX_DATUM
 , :TTX_DATUM2  + 1
 , :TTX_EMP_ID
)
```

3 - Define 4 ptInput parameters of type `ftInteger`,`ftdateTime`,`ftdateTime` and `ftInteger`.

4 - Execute the query:

```
with FDQuery1 do
begin
  Params[0].AsInteger  := Random(100);
  Params[1].AsDateTime := Now;
  Params[2].AsDateTime := Now;
  Params[3].AsInteger  := Random(100)+100;
  ExecSQL;
end;
```

This seems to convert parameter #2 to a [datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) type and gives the error `Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int`. That's [not an unknown error here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Operand+type+clash%3A+datetime2+is+incompatible+with+int) ;-). I can fix this with e.g.

```
INSERT INTO TESTCAL
 (TT_CALENDAR_ID
 ,TT_START
 ,TT_FINISH
 ,TT_EMP_ID
)
VALUES
(:ID
 , :TTX_DATUM
 , DATEADD(dd,1,:TTX_DATUM2)
 , :TTX_EMP_ID
)
```

But: **Can I prevent the error without changing the SQL command itself**?
Because: This kind of code is in different (custom) scripts running on many clients' computers. The error now starts occuring after the switch to FireDAC.

Comment: why not simply do `:TTX_DATUM2,` and in code `Params[2].AsDateTime := Now + 1`

Comment: @GuidoG Yes, but that would not meet the criterium *without changing the SQL command*.

Comment: Adding 1 to a datetime is something that Delphi does... but it is not supported by most SQL servers. That is why they provide DATEADD or similar functions to implement date algebra. Your SQL, as is, is just plain wrong, and the error is telling you just that. So you cannot prevent the error without changing the SQL because the error is in the SQL statement you are submitting, not in the parameter values.

Comment: @Frazz, agreed, but it's a driver's fault in this case. Philosophical quesion; if we lose how bad is adding date this way, why does driver describe the command parameter the same way if you add 1 or not, if it cannot run the command after?

Comment: @Victoria, why is this the driver's fault? Are you saying that the first query will execute correctly from within SQL Server?

Comment: @Frazz, because it treats those parameters as `DATETIME2`, not `DATETIME`. And who else describes the parameters than driver? FireDAC performs implicit conversions for you, so it's not about the values. It's the driver who says, look, this parameter in the prepared command is `DATETIME2`. If it would be described as `DATETIME`, the command would execute. And I agree of course, you should avoid such constructions in general as you said (and use the mentioned `DATEADD`, or better yet, FireDAC's `TIMESTAMPADD` macro).

Answer (score 0):

In [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations), Aaron Bertrand shows several bad habits of date calculations and advises (like some of the commenters did) to stop doing these kind of integer/date calculations:

> So the moral of this segment is simply to always explicitly state what you are doing, and stop using fancy shorthand that will not work as fluently as you might expect across all the systems where your code might end up. You'll type a little more, but your code will also be better insulated from date type changes.

We'll follow this advice, bite the bullet, and start updating these scripts using DATEADD() (so dropping the requirement *without changing the SQL command itself* in the question).